# Python Machine Learning Warning

Tags: python

I am using the following python program to implement a basic decision tree classifier.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np

features = [[140,1],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
labels = [0,0,1,1]

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = clf.fit(features, labels)
a = model.predict ([160,0])
print (a)
```

It prints out the predicted value but gives a warning,

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and   
willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1,    
1) if   your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a 
single sample.
```

I have tried to fix it using this,

```
features = np.array(features).reshape(-1, 2)
labels = np.array(labels).reshape(-1, 1)
```

But this showed the same warning. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you make those changes, do you get the same warning or a different problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with model.predict. This works:

    `a = model.predict ([[160,0]])`